# symbol lookup error: node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v86LockerC1EPNS_7IsolateE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js

I am try to use ember.js with rails, I follow the railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/408-ember-part-1 and get this error

```
Showing /home/william/codes/408-ember-part-1/raffler-    after/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

node: symbol lookup error: node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v86LockerC1EPNS_7IsolateE

  (in /home/william/codes/408-ember-part-1/raffler- after/app/assets/javascripts/store.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>Raffler</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
Rails.root: /home/william/codes/408-ember-part-1/raffler-after
```

at the beginning I think it may be some thing I made wrong, but as you can see, I try the source code from railscast, still get this error

I am use openSUSE 12.3 and installed nodejs as javascript compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by install nodejs from source